# Azure Analysis Service Roles conflict with roles in database of source?

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-analysis-services

I'm migrating an on-premise application (basically a database + a dashboard) to Azure. In my database on-premise, I had set up some access rules and RSL (Row Level Security) for different user profiles. Those were done at the level of my database which is postgres.

Now on the plateforme of Azure, I have to add an intermediare layer, Azure Analysis service between my postgres and dashboard. I want to know how to ensure my database access management & RLS with the addition of Azure Analysis service.

Do I need to replicate it in Analysis Service? Or it will still work and I do nothing with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand in the intial design you did not have AAS and the RLS was at the database level . Once you moved to Azure you introduced the AAS ( may be to boost performance) , to me it should work fine . We will have to think how will you refresh the data from the database to AAS and for that you may have add an user .